# Error with call Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync(cb);

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-app

call the this function return OSF.DDA.Error "Internal protocol error: '-2'
Why?

Exchange server 2013 on custom server, OWA

Comment: Could you add some extra details here?

Comment: Exchange server 2013

Comment: OSF.DDA.Error {name: 1, message: "Internal protocol error: '-2'.", code: undefined}
status
:
"failed"
value
:
null